# Sessions are not persistent using Nodejs Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session, passport.js

I'm creating REST APIs using NodeJS and MongoDB as a database.

I'm using `passport` for handling the authentication.

I'm wondering why the sessions are not persistent! Also why the deserialization is never invoked!

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    console.log(user, "deserialization"); // --> Never invoked!
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }) // --> Sessions has been saved to database after each login or register
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

exports.getRestaurants = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session); // --> Not contains any user info
  console.log(req.user); // -->undefined and this is my problem
  const restaurants = await liveRestaurants.find().sort({ rate: -1 });
  if (!restaurants) return next();
  res.status(200).json({ restaurants });
};
```

After my research, I concluded that it might be for the following reasons:

- app.use should be in the correct order
- localhost port have an effect on it "as I read"
- cluster
- and other

Comment: Have you tried moving the `app.use(session...` to after `app.use(passport.session)`?

Comment: No I didn't but app.user(session... shou before before passport.session. Thanks for you comment @RGreenstreet